# What is the bit at the end of a PGP signature file

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I have a PGP signature:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

iQEcBAABCAAGBQJX192XAAoJEBMxnLaYuadNVV8H/j5P9CJUnRfBGEtAXAJry35x
SXgVhx4WsC3uHZmWLaGDtzYg3sfZKgKrYLfJn7NP6vAe3PvxxIVbXw28trAneYlE
bv1ogqBO/waWecJIR+WimeTbHyKK/cEKQk+6nV8Q7/BhxE7RcbeEhbSn+JWhtjwu
UubjKr6KZvSPPD7LeA59E96fSksVypg/Em1ZMM3MzmRHKc6pKJuG2SKLUaN0hPt4
sux6ZKq+yKBz/k/iYkfbazyYK4PZgcRijb9P7Cfkoe5DD2kdMNOFgW3N9+4Zie+O
aQe23xwh5p3rb2/zHTbUU6YcTyAK8Js/xnR4Aih0Nd43tEvOOTXc1NnVe7jE4jE=
=lMwp
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I can use bouncy castle to generate the first couple of lines but there is a `=lMwp` at the end of the signature that I don't know where to find or what it is.

Is it a checksum of some kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a checksum of some kind?

Exactly. From [RFC 4880 (OpenPGP) Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6):

> 6. Radix-64 Conversions
>    ... OpenPGP's Radix-64 encoding is composed of two parts: a base64
>    encoding of the binary data **and a checksum**.  The base64 encoding is
>    identical to the MIME base64 content-transfer-encoding [RFC2045].
>    The checksum is a 24-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) **converted to
>    four characters of radix-64 encoding** by the same MIME base64
>    transformation, **preceded by an equal sign (=)** ...
>    The checksum with its leading equal sign MAY appear on the **first line
>    after the base64 encoded data**.

If you want to know how exactly the checksum is computed so you can recreate or verify it just read on in this section.